# Apply opacity to all body except one image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a html code with 3 images

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Tias</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/estilo.css">
    <script src="../js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/animate.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="cuerpo">
    <h1>Tias famosas</h1>

    <img src="has.jpg" class="tias-imagen">
    <img src="dew.jpg" class="tias-imagen">
    <img src="hola.jpg" class="tias-imagen">

    </div>
</body>
```

Then I have a js file

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".tias-imagen").on('click', function() {
        $(this).animate({
            width: "70%",
            height: "800px",
            marginLeft: "0.6in",
            fontSize: "3em",
            borderWidth: "10px"
        }, 1500 );
        $(".cuerpo").not(this).animate({
            opacity: "0.4"
        }, 1500);
    });
});
```

So then when I click on the image I want the opacity background have an opacity of 0,4.

But I don't want that the opacity apply on the image.

However in the js code it does put the opacity to all elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are applying opacity to div with class `.cuerpo`. So it will effect all children in div. Instead of that select all children in `div` without the `image` that clicked using:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".tias-imagen").on('click', function() {
        $(this).animate({
            width: "70%",
            height: "800px",
            marginLeft: "0.6in",
            fontSize: "3em",
            borderWidth: "10px"
        }, 1500 );
        $(".cuerpo").find("*").not(this).animate({
            opacity: "0.4"
        }, 1500);
    });
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/trw2V/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Separate the background div and the img content. **[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/BlackSRC/trw2V/5/)**

**HTML & CSS**

```
<style>
.container
{
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    position:relative;
}
.img, .cuerpo
{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:0; left:0;
}
.cuerpo
{
    z-index:-10;
}
</style>

<div class='container'>
    <div class="cuerpo">
        <h1>Tias famosas</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="img">
        <img src="has.jpg" class="tias-imagen">
        <img src="dew.jpg" class="tias-imagen">
        <img src="hola.jpg" class="tias-imagen">
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".tias-imagen").on('click', function() {
        $(this).animate({
            width: "70%",
            height: "800px",
            marginLeft: "0.6in",
            fontSize: "3em",
            borderWidth: "10px",
            opacity: "1",
        }, 1500 );
        $(".cuerpo, .tias-imagen").not(this).animate({
            opacity: "0.4"
        }, 1500);
    });
});
```